# Formula to sort rows of bank statement

Tags: google-sheets

I export my bank transactions to a PDF, that I then paste to a google spreadsheet.

Problem is: I may need to sort the transactions on my spreadsheet, and after reordering by date the amounts and balance may "shift" when there are several transactions on the same day:

[image]

It's not a big problem to me, but my accountant is all lost.

I would like to find a way to identify the orders of the transactions of a same date, by comparing the amounts/balance to the final balance of the previous date.

I managed to create a formula using a MATCH that would identify the first transaction of a specific date, but if I were to make it work for 10-20 potential transactions within a same date, it would get stupidly long and complex. I may eventually do that, but before i'd like to know if there is an easier solution.

I can add as many columns as I want, and I don't mind using scripts.
What I cannot do is create a column that would recalculate the balance according to the order the transactions are in. That would be the easiest solution, but if my accountant were to compare with what is on the real bank account, he would find discrepancies and be just as lost.

Thank you!

Comment: How are your bank transactions ordered in the PDF?

Comment: Is is possible to add another column before you do any sorting that would contain a number in each row, starting at 1, and incremented by 1 until the last row in your data?  That way you can always revert back to the original order by sorting that column.

Comment: They are sorted correctly in the PDF (although, depending on the bank, some PDF are sorted from more newest to oldest, and others from oldest to newest). The problem occurs when I sort and resort in the google spreadsheet (and because of the type of work i need to do with the spreadsheet, it's unavoidable)

Answer (score 0):

As [@gries](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9587548/gries) said:

Since your PDF contains the transactions already ordered the way you want you can assign to each of them an incremental ID.

In such a way, you will be able to restore the initial order ordering by the transaction ID instead of using the date that could be repeated.